# Change directory of command

Tags: environment-variables, path

I have two versions of PHP:

```
macabeus@macabeus-acer ~ $ whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/X11/php /usr/share/php /opt/php-my-version-7.0/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

macabeus@macabeus-acer ~ $ php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 (cli) (built: Jul 28 2016 19:31:33) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

And, I want to use `/opt/php-my-version-7.0/bin/php`, but, my system is using the version from `/usr/bin/php` by default. How to change to my system to use version from `/opt/php-my-version-7.0/bin/php` by default?

Comment: I also noticed your path for *which php* is very long. Default path= */usr/bin/php*

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which modules of php that may be served by apache
*/opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf*
This is the global configuration file for apache, apache modules are imported from here.
**However**
To set the php version for your project, in the main directory's **.htaccess**
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .php`

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about running from the command line it is going to use the first one it finds in $PATH. You can change your $PATH variable so that /opt/php-my-version-7.0/bin appears at the front.

```
 export PATH=/opt/php-my-version-7.0/bin:$PATH
```

If you add this line to ~/.profile it will make each new login shell you start run that automatically.

For Apache CGI support (unusual for php) you can set path in `/etc/apache2/envvars` just add the same line to that file.

If you want Apache to load mod_php from there you will need to change the apache configuration to load that version of the libphp7.so file (assuming you have a version that was built with mod_php support). Look for an example file in your install documentation.